# Installing Ubuntu 14 from bootable USB with updated packages

Tags: 14.04

I want to install Ubuntu 14 Desktop on PC which doesn't have internet. So I created a bootable USB of Ubuntu, installed all updates including KDevelop. Then I installed Ubuntu from it on my PC, but the KDevelop and other updates are not refelecting in the installation. When I boot from USB, KDevelop is running, but not from hard disk.

What could be solution? Please let me have your suggestions.

Comment: Suggestion: You can also install any packages that you need without an internet connection after installing Ubuntu from a [vanilla](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/vanilla) Ubuntu installation media. Look at this question: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline).

Comment: Its done, Was quite easy. Copied cache->apt->archive folder from bootable disk to my computer in tmp folder. Then simply installed all *.deb files. Thanks for the suggestion.